# Want to make code segment into library file

Tags: java, android

Trying to build my own library. My code is :

```
public void simpleToast(String message, int duration) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
```

}

as the file simpleToast.java and I know I need

```
package com.myxxx;
import java.io.xx;
```

first, but then how do I frame code into expected 'class' or 'interface'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right, except for the Context thing.Do it like this :

```
Class UIUtils{
public static void simpleToast(String message, int duration,Context context) {
toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
}
```

Now if you want to use this method in other activity,like

```
UIUtils.simpleToast(this , message , duration);
```

Comment: Great! Now I just need to remember how to eliminate using the "UIUtils." before uniquely named method... import it?